# Difference between Option(Optimize For Unknown) and option(Optimize for (@parameter Unknown))

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have two stored procedures. In one of the procedures, the code uses the following hint:
option(Optimize for Unknown). The other stored procedure uses this hint:
option(Optimize for (@id Unknown). @id is a parameter that is being passed to the stored proc.
What is the difference between these two hints?

Comment: Explained in the [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query#optimize-for--variable_name--unknown---literal_constant-_---n--). `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` is the universal application of `OPTIMIZE FOR (@x UNKNOWN)` to all variables in the query. Incidentally, unless the procedures are executed many times per second, `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` tends to yield better results as the execution plan can then be tuned for particular values, but there are circumstances where even that can lead to sub-optimal plans and `UNKNOWN` is better.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jeroen! I have requirement where instead of passing one value for @id I need to pass multiple values using an xml string. In this case, how can I change the Optimize For hint since my understanding is that it only accepts one value?

Comment: Why would you use an XML string instead of a TVP? And no `OPTIMIZE FOR` can't really deal with either of those scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron! The XML string is coming from the application and so I don't have much control over it.

Comment: You can still shred the XML server-side and store it in a table variable or temp table. `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the query using that table may be necessary to get decent performance (especially if you use a table variable, since otherwise the optimizer will assume the table has only one row). If you use a temp table, the optimizer will have access to statistics. As a last resort the input could be used to build a query dynamically.

Comment: And what exact problem are you attempting to "optimize" with hints? Perhaps you don't need them at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**From the docs:**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15#optimize-for-unknown) *(my bold)*

> **OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN**
>
> Instructs the Query Optimizer to use the average selectivity of the predicate across **all column values** instead of using the runtime parameter value when the query is compiled and optimized.
>
> If you use `OPTIMIZE FOR @variable_name = literal_constant` and `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` in **the same query hint**, the Query Optimizer will use the `literal_constant` specified for a specific value. The Query Optimizer will use `UNKNOWN` for the rest of the variable values. The values are used only during query optimization, and not during query execution.

So `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` will apply `OPTIMIZE FOR @variable_name UNKNOWN` to each variable that is not already specified with `OPTIMIZE FOR`